# Convert Unix into XML for SMS Notification

Tags: xml, unix

```
echo '' > $OUTDIR/one/ICS0901.${rundtDate}.${rundtTime}.xml

while read -r line; do

    value1=$(echo "$line"| awk -F"|" '{print $1}')

    value2=$(echo "$line"| awk -F"|" '{print $4}')

    echo '63'$value1'' >> $OUTDIR/one/ICS0901.${rundtDate}.${rundtTime}.xml

    echo ' '$value2'' >> $OUTDIR/one/ICS0901.${rundtDate}.${rundtTime}.xml
```

Can you help me to create a XML file using this unix script above?

In order to create a SMS Notification

- value1 is for the mobile numbers
- value2 is for the Notification message

Comment: Please explain the expected format of the XML file and how the contents of `value1` and `value2` look like.

Comment: for the value1 = 639171234567 and for the value2 = "This is a Test"

Comment: And how should the XML file look like? Please provide an example with more than one pair of value1 and value2.

Comment: See below example:

<NotificationRecords>
 <NotificationRecord>
 <userIdentity>639171234567</userIdentity> ----> value1
 <userIdentityType>0</userIdentityType>
 <notifPatternId>Testr</notifPatternId>
 <notifGroupId>1</notifGroupId>
 <notifPriority>50</notifPriority>
 <notifText></notifText>
 <notifParam>
  <name>Test</name>
  <value>This is a test.</value> ---->value2
 </notifParam>
 </NotificationRecord>